# LMC555 delay off timer, M20 motor drive, updated

Tags: mosfet, timer, 555, npn, delay

The goal is to either just give a signal to the motor with momentary switch, or turn on the toggle switch, let 3.7V motor run for a couple of seconds before 440uF is fully charged, after which voltage on that side will get higher than the other, so the comparator will shut off the output. Please help me make this circuit impeccable.

1. Do I need a voltage regulator [MCP1700](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/MCP1700-Low-Quiescent-Current-LDO-20001826E.pdf) for M20 motor? Fully charged battery is 4.2V, and motor operation is rated from 3 - 3.7V.
2. Is it [DMG2302UK](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/DMG2302UK.pdf) appropriate NFET for this case? What about [Si2342DS](https://www.vishay.com/docs/63302/si2342ds.pdf)? "DMG" is stated as a motor driver, but "Si" has lower Rds at the same Vgs.
3. Will [1N4001](https://www.vishay.com/docs/88503/1n4001.pdf) serve enough as a Flyback diode?
4. Are there any other precautions I should take to make this circuit durable and safe? Should I put a diode in series before C6 to prevent a backflow?

[image: Updated schematic]

I was "forced" to join two posts together, as people started down-voting new post for some reason. Following down is the old post, which is probably no longer a case:

Title: TLC555 vs LMC555, delay off timer with 3.7V bat for 3V motor

I made that circuit with online circuit testing tool, and I am getting an error - 1 bad connection. But in practice it works at is it supposed to.

My question is:

1. I am talking only about life time and safety here - for this setup, which would be more optimal a TLC555 or a LMC555? Or even any other alternative I should look into? All I need 555 for is to shut motor off.
   Datasheet:
   -[TLC555](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlc555.pdf?ts=1691570559801&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com.cn%252Fproduct%252Fzh-cn%252FTLC555%252Fpart-details%252FTLC555CDR%253FkeyMatch%253DTLC555CDR%2526tisearch%253Dsearch-everything%2526usecase%253DOPN)
   -[LMC555](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmc555.pdf?ts=1691600012609&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F)
2. I have two capacitors on the motor. Polarized is there to elongate operating time and soften it, and a small ceramic is there to cut off the noise. Will a polarized capacitor do all jobs done, or is it better to also leave a 10nF ceramic parallel to it?
3. Diode 1N4001 will do it for the reverse polarization protection?
4. I also added 10nF ceramic capacitor on the Control pin, but what about the ground/vcc, are they better to also have some "filtering" element?
5. Should I connect a vcc and reset pin to get more current on the output or in this case wouldn't matter? Because the motor is on a high side, and it bypasses 555 through the NPN transistor, right?
6. I am not sure about which NPN transistor to choose and if a 1k  resistor on the gate is optimal. If I calculate this right, I now only get 4mA on the output (4 / 1000), which isn't even 1/20 of the current going through collector. The motor (small M20 vibrator) max current is probably less than 200mA, so I am not 100% sure what kind of SMD transistor is safe to put there. MMBT2369L has a Continuous Collector Current:     200 mA, but also a Maximum DC Collector Current:    200 mA.
7. Are there any other precautions I should take to make this circuit durable and safe?
   [image]

And this how the capacitors are supposed to be located (from LMC datasheet):

[image]

Comment: Check timing, it is much more than 2 seconds. Reset pin should be connected to Vcc. Also a diode from capacitor (anode) and cathode connected to Vcc will discharge the capacitor to a new timing cycle. About transistor, better look for N channel MOSFET with low Vgs, you will save Base current and will have lower drop voltage.

Comment: You also need a bypass capacitor across the power supply (battery) near the 555. And make sure your device is rated for operation on 3.7V (and lower as battery loses charge).

Comment: @Bravale Thank you! You are right, it lasts much more. I connected reset to Vcc. Should I also connect pin 7 to 3? It is said to do that "to get a slightly better SINK capability from the chip", and I am not sure what this means. I would prefer to have slight voltage drop as battery in full state reaches 4.2V and the motor is made for 3 - 3.7V.

Comment: @PStechPaul Thanks! Please check corrected schematic. I added 3x 1uF bypass capacitors. Is this ok? or 0.1μF would be better? I am not sure if I need all 3 of them. Anyway, 1st is on the battery, 2nd on IC and the 3rd NPN. How to calculate the resistor for the 3rd one? I now added 500Ohm randomly.

Comment: Your 555 has no complete part number. If it is an NE555 or LM555 then it WILL NOT WORK because its datasheet says its minimum supply is 4.5V.

Comment: The transistor base current must be 1/10th its collector current for it to have good saturation. Your base current is much too low using a 1k base resistor. But a Cmos 555 cannot produce enough base current anyway,

Comment: @Audioguru you are right, I'll add this to the schematic. So TLC555I is what I am testing. It has recommended supply voltage 3 -15V (MIN = 2V). It has 150mA Sink, discharge or output max current.

Comment: @Audioguru are you saying I must use a mosfet? Even if I replace the base resistor for 100Ohm? The problem with mosfet is, that it has close to 0 voltage drop, and fully charge battery can be as high as 4.2V

Comment: @PStechPaul is there a way to assume the frequency on my NPN transistor without using a oscilloscope? If I would only know what frequency to filter out, there is an easy tool to calculate it: http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/Bypass-capacitor-calculator.php#answer

Comment: @Audioguru On some forum I found out what u were saying for CMOS 555: "At 5v, the chip will deliver 2mA and sink only 8mA". The question is if this still fits nowadays, if the data sheet stays different numbers for TLC?

Comment: @PStechPaul I followed your advice and joined both questions/posts together.

Comment: @Justme here you go. I hope this is more edible now.

Comment: @Bravale "Also a diode from capacitor (anode) and cathode connected to Vcc will discharge the capacitor to a new timing cycle." What does that mean? That capacitor will empty each time when the switch is off? Isn't this what happens anyway?

Comment: What If I connect big bulk C7 directly to the ground?

Comment: @Bravale "The capacitor will empty when the switch is off, but will take the same or more time of charging if it is done through the resistor R1." This refers to C1, and I get it. But I don't get that: "A diode will discharge the capacitor faster, and the timer will not be affected if switch is operated quickly." refers to C1 and C7? Are you saying that each click will restart the timer to 0 (which is good), but will eat more current because capacitors will empty through a kickback diode? Can you give me some tip on how to position them? I would like to have C7 close to the motor.

Comment: @Domenico: nothing to do with C7, only C1 (timing capacitor).  Current in restart will be limited by R1, should be no problem. See D3 in schematics https://i.imgur.com/1PZGGyj.jpg

Comment: @Bravale oh, I see. So you are saying I should put another diode if I want C1 to empty in between cycles? So each restart will be from 0 time, right?

Comment: So C7 can stay connected straight to the motor - kickback diode won't affect it?

Comment: Thank-you for adding the part number TLC555i and an LMC555 is the same. Their max allowed output current is sourcing 150mA but with a supply that is only 3V (when the battery is discharged) the max output sourcing is only 0.3mA with a 1.5V voltage loss. When the battery is 5V (its max voltage is only 4.2V when fully charged) its max output sourcing is only 1mA.

Comment: @Audioguru Thanks man. I'm still struggling to solve it, though I found an mosfet DMG2302UK to drive the motor. And I removed MCP voltage regulator as the new motor I've set has 3 - 4.2V max.